# html2canvas generates a blank image

Tags: html2canvas

after some googling around, I haven't been able to wrap my head around why this script isn't working. The goal is to have a button that, when clicked, will generate an image download of my div with the id save.

Currently, clicking the download button DOES generate an image download, but the image is always blank/empty. Why is it not grabbing my div successfully?

Here's my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="save" id='save'>
        <div class="center">
            <h1 class="alignleft">This is a heading</h1>
            <p class="alignright"><a href="https://twitter.com/mrjpweaver">@asdf</a></p>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras tempus placerat fringilla. Sed rutrum tortor et lobortis egestas. Morbi cursus, ex nec pharetra fringilla, nisl libero convallis leo, vitae volutpat arcu enim in mi. Suspendisse a enim molestie justo laoreet fermentum at ac neque. Donec vel cursus orci, vel blandit est. Suspendisse fringilla vel nulla quis mollis. Mauris orci urna, dignissim id erat a, posuere congue turpis. Integer blandit sed felis ut vehicula. Phasellus et dui quis orci dictum vulputate. Pellentesque pretium eget diam et euismod. Nunc rutrum vehicula nisl, at sagittis enim sollicitudin quis.<br>

            Mauris et sagittis eros. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nam ante ante, faucibus nec dapibus a, tristique ac turpis. Maecenas at ipsum a mauris luctus blandit. Nam convallis lacus dui, pulvinar interdum arcu malesuada id. Integer convallis semper purus in sodales. Mauris ac laoreet augue.</p>

            <div class="nav">
                <a href="blue.html">next -></a>
            </div>

                 <a id="btn-Convert-Html2Image" href="#">Download</a>
                <br />
                <div id="previewImage" style="display: none;">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var element = $("#save"); // global variable
            var getCanvas; // global variable

            html2canvas(element, {
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
                    getCanvas = canvas;
                }
            });

            $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").on('click', function () {
                var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
                // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
                var newData = imgageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
                $("#btn-Convert-Html2Image").attr("download", "poem.png").attr("href", newData);
            });
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a reference to JQuery UI as well:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

It works fine for me per this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/n5gcbstu/

Only difference in the fiddle and your code seems to be that **I have JQueryUI referenced as well.**

Comment: I pasted that reference into my html header, but still no luck. It works flawlessly in that fiddle, but not on my server. Maybe I need to add a library or something on the server? Kind of at a loss here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I figured out the problem. It wasn't related to referencing JQuery UI, it was some CSS I was using to center my div. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Code worked without the Jquery UI reference, it was my CSS centering the div that was messing it up. Replaced with this CSS and life is good:

```
.center {
    margin: auto;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
}
body {
    background-color: lightgrey;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the one that does not work as well? Thanks